# Rails/POSTGRES ISDATE function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, date

I'd like to change all non-date formatted strings to date nil, then change a column type. I had planned to use the below:

```
class SetSubmitDateForAllMyTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    MyTable.connection.execute("UPDATE my_table SET submit_date = NULL WHERE NOT ISDATE(submit_date)")
    MyTable.connection.execute("UPDATE my_table SET submit_date=created_at WHERE submit_date IS NULL")
    change_column :my_table, :submit_date, :date
  end

  def self.down

  end
end
```

However, the ISDATE function doesn't seem to be valid in POSTGRES. How can I accomplish this?

I am open to using:

```
MyTable.all.each do |list|
```

Comment: Is this a one-time change? What's the data look like?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' This should be a migrate that can be run on any environment that does not yet have this migrate, so hopefully a one time. The field is a string, so it could hold anything alpha-numeric.

Comment: The phrase *anything alpha-numeric* covers a host of sins when you're talking about a date conversion. Can it *really* contain values like 'wibble', '01/02/03', 'Apr 4, 1963', 'Jug 134, 2015'?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' It is unlikely, but yes, it can. Generally, it will either be a blank string or a date formatted like 01/02/2014 or 2014-01-02. I am prepared for a margin of error.

Comment: If this is just a one off I'd write a PL/pgSQL function which tried to cast a string to a date, trapped the "can't cast" exception, and returned NULL on the exception. The do an ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN with a USING clause to use that function to do the conversion. Then delete the function when you're done. Or do a bunch of regex wrangling to standardize your data format and set everything else to NULL.

Comment: @muistooshort Submit this as an answer. I did this, but in a rails migration that checked to see if the column was of type string first, so in future migrations it will essentially skip this if it was already a date.

Comment: You're welcome to self-answer this one, I was too lazy to write a proper answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgresql can coerce strings to date, but it will error on invalid strings:

```
dev_db=> select '1/2/2015'::date;
    date
------------
 2015-01-02

dev_db=> select 'asdf'::date;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "asdf"
LINE 1: select 'asdf'::date;
               ^
```

To get around this, you could create a Postgresql function to check if a string is a valid date, but really it would be much easier to just handle the conversion on each record in your migration.